# I can't make my JavaScript load this XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Whenever I try to load an XML file using a JS script, the inspector says this

```
Could not load XML resource: "unicode-conversion.xml"
unicode.js:45 Exception:"<unicode>
<font name="Bold">
<letter source="a" target=""/>
<letter source="b" target=""/>
<letter source="c" target=""/>
<letter source="d" target=""/>
<letter source="e" target=""/>
<letter source="f" target=""/>
<letter source="g" target=""/>
<letter source="h" target=""/>
<letter source="i" target=""/>
<letter source="j" target=""/>
<letter source="k" target=""/>
<letter source="l" target=""/>
<letter source="m" target=""/>
<letter source="n" target=""/>
<letter source="o" target=""/>
<letter source="p" target=""/>
<letter source="q" target=""/>
<letter source="r" target=""/>
<letter source="s" target=""/>
<letter source="t" target=""/>
<letter source="u" target=""/>
<letter source="v" target=""/>
<letter source="w" target=""/>
<letter source="x" target=""/>
<letter source="y" target=""/>
<letter source="z" target=""/>
<letter source="A" target=""/>
<letter source="B" target=""/>
<letter source="C" target=""/>
<letter source="D" target=""/>
<letter source="E" target=""/>
<letter source="F" target=""/>
<letter source="G" target=""/>
<letter source="H" target=""/>
<letter source="I" target=""/>
<letter source="J" target=""/>
<letter source="K" target=""/>
<letter source="L" target=""/>
<letter source="M" target=""/>
<letter source="N" target=""/>
<letter source="O" target=""/>
<letter source="P" target=""/>
<letter source="Q" target=""/>
<letter source="R" target=""/>
<letter source="S" target=""/>
<letter source="T" target=""/>
<letter source="U" target=""/>
<letter source="V" target=""/>
<letter source="W" target=""/>
<letter source="X" target=""/>
<letter source="Y" target=""/>
<letter source="Z" target=""/>
<letter source="0" target=""/>
<letter source="1" target=""/>
<letter source="2" target=""/>
<letter source="3" target=""/>
<letter source="4" target=""/>
<letter source="5" target=""/>
<letter source="6" target=""/>
<letter source="7" target=""/>
<letter source="8" target=""/>
<letter source="9" target=""/>
<letter source="!" target="❗"/>
<letter source="?" target="❓"/>
<letter source="." target="."/>
<letter source="," target=","/>
<letter source=""" target="""/>
<letter source="'" target="'"/>
</font>
<font name="Italics">
<letter source="a" target=""/>
<letter source="b" target=""/>
<letter source="c" target=""/>
<letter source="d" target=""/>
<letter source="e" target=""/>
<letter source="f" target=""/>
<letter source="g" target=""/>
<letter source="h" target=""/>
<letter source="i" target=""/>
<letter source="j" target=""/>
<letter source="k" target=""/>
<letter source="l" target=""/>
<letter source="m" target=""/>
<letter source="n" target=""/>
<letter source="o" target=""/>
<letter source="p" target=""/>
<letter source="q" target=""/>
<letter source="r" target=""/>
<letter source="s" target=""/>
<letter source="t" target=""/>
<letter source="u" target=""/>
<letter source="v" target=""/>
<letter source="w" target=""/>
<letter source="x" target=""/>
<letter source="y" target=""/>
<letter source="z" target=""/>
<letter source="A" target=""/>
<letter source="B" target=""/>
<letter source="C" target=""/>
<letter source="D" target=""/>
<letter source="E" target=""/>
<letter source="F" target=""/>
<letter source="G" target=""/>
<letter source="H" target=""/>
<letter source="I" target=""/>
<letter source="J" target=""/>
<letter source="K" target=""/>
<letter source="L" target=""/>
<letter source="M" target=""/>
<letter source="N" target=""/>
<letter source="O" target=""/>
<letter source="P" target=""/>
<letter source="Q" target=""/>
<letter source="R" target=""/>
<letter source="S" target=""/>
<letter source="T" target=""/>
<letter source="U" target=""/>
<letter source="V" target=""/>
<letter source="W" target=""/>
<letter source="X" target=""/>
<letter source="Y" target=""/>
<letter source="Z" target=""/>
<letter source="0" target="0"/>
<letter source="1" target="1"/>
<letter source="2" target="2"/>
<letter source="3" target="3"/>
<letter source="4" target="4"/>
<letter source="5" target="5"/>
<letter source="6" target="6"/>
<letter source="7" target="7"/>
<letter source="8" target="8"/>
<letter source="9" target="9"/>
<letter source="!" target="!"/>
<letter source="?" target="?"/>
<letter source="." target="."/>
<letter source="," target=","/>
<letter source=""" target="""/>
<letter source="'" target="'"/>
</font>
<font name="Bold Italics">
<letter source="a" target=""/>
<letter source="b" target=""/>
<letter source="c" target=""/>
<letter source="d" target=""/>
<letter source="e" target=""/>
<letter source="f" target=""/>
<letter source="g" target=""/>
<letter source="h" target=""/>
<letter source="i" target="'
```

Also, while it gives no errors, it shows an alert saying:
"Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

I'm using http-server and my local files so it's not in the internet yet. I also leave here my JS code in case it's needed to solve the issue. Basically, it's an unicode converter that works through an "oninput" DOM event in a textarea.

```js
var NS = {
 XML    : "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace",
 HTML    : "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
 SVG    : "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
 XLINK    : "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
 XSL    : "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
 MOZ_XUL   : "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul",
 MOZ_ERR_PARSE  : "http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml",
 IBP    : "http://www.ibp-dresden.de",
 LLO    : "http://slothsoft.net",
 resolver : function(prefix) {
  return NS[prefix.toUpperCase()];
 },
 prefixer : function(uri) {
  var prefix, ret = "";
  for (prefix in NS) {
   if (NS[prefix] === uri) {
    ret = prefix;
    break;
   }
  }
  return ret.toLowerCase();
 },
};

var DOM = {
 loadDocument : function(uri) {
  var retDoc, req;
  try {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", uri, false);
   if (req.overrideMimeType) {
    //req.overrideMimeType("application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
   }
   req.send();
   if (req.responseXML) {
    retDoc = req.responseXML;
   } else {
    //retDoc = this.loadXML(req.responseText);
    throw req.responseText;
   }
   retDoc.fileURI = uri;
  } catch (e) {
   console.log("Could not load XML resource: %o", uri);
   console.log("Exception:%o", e);
   retDoc = false;
  }
  return retDoc;
 },
 saveDocument : function(uri, doc) {
  var ret, req;
  try {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("POST", uri, false);
   //req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
   req.send(doc);
   ret = req.responseXML;
  } catch (e) {
   console.log("Could not save XML resource: %o", uri);
   console.log("Exception:%o", e);
   ret = false;
  }
  return ret;
 },
 loadXML : function(xml) {
  var doc, parser;
  parser = new DOMParser();
  doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
  if (doc.documentElement.namespaceURI === NS.MOZ_ERR_PARSE) {
   throw ""+doc.documentElement.textContent;
  }
  return doc;
 },
 saveXML : function(doc) {
  var xml, serializer;
  serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  xml = serializer.serializeToString(doc);
  return xml;
 }
};

var DOMHelper = {
 loadDocument : function(uri, callback) {
  try {
   let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", uri, false);
   if (req.overrideMimeType) {
    //req.overrideMimeType("application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
   }
   if (callback) {
    req.addEventListener(
     "loadend",
     (eve) => {
      let retDoc = req.responseXML;
      if (retDoc) {
       retDoc.fileURI = uri;
      } else {
       retDoc = false;
       
       console.log("Could not load XML resource: %o", uri);
       console.log(req.responseText);
      }
      callback(retDoc);
     },
     false
    );
   }
   req.send();
  } catch (e) {
   console.log("Could not load XML resource: %o", uri);
   console.log("Exception:%o", e);
  }
 },
};

var XPath = {
 evaluate : function(query, contextNode) {
  var ownerDoc, res, ret, tmp, isTextNode;
  if (contextNode instanceof Array) {
   ret = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < contextNode.length; i++) {
    res = this.evaluate(query, contextNode[i]);
    if (res instanceof Array) {
     ret = ret.concat(res);
    } else {
     ret.push(res);
    }
   }
   return ret;
  }
  try {
   ownerDoc = contextNode.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE
    ? contextNode
    : contextNode.ownerDocument;
   //use wgxpath
   if (window.wgxpath) {
    if (!window.document.evaluate) {
     window.wgxpath.install(window);
    }
    if (!ownerDoc.evaluate) {
     window.wgxpath.install( { document : ownerDoc } );
    }
   }
   //alert(ownerDoc + "\n" + ownerDoc.evaluate + "\n" + ownerDoc.selectNodes);
   isTextNode = false;
   if (contextNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    if (contextNode.nodeValue === "") {
     contextNode.nodeValue = " ";
     isTextNode = true;
    }
   }
   res = ownerDoc.evaluate(query, contextNode, NS.resolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
   switch (res.resultType) {
    case XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE:
     ret = res.numberValue;
     break;
    case XPathResult.STRING_TYPE:
     ret = res.stringValue;
     break;
    case XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE:
     ret = res.booleanValue;
     break;
    default:
     ret = [];
     while (tmp = res.iterateNext()) {
      ret.push(tmp);
     }
     break;
   }
   //window.console.log("XPath result type: %o (%o)", res.resultType, typeof ret);
   if (isTextNode) {
    contextNode.nodeValue = "";
   }
   return ret;
  } catch(e) {
   window.console.log("XPath error!");
   window.console.log("Query:%o", query);
   window.console.log("Context node:%o", contextNode);
   window.console.log("Exception:%o", e);
   throw e;
  }
 },
 createPath : function(contextNode) {
  var node, nodeList, i, ret = [""], tag, precedingList, followingList;
  nodeList = this.evaluate("ancestor-or-self::node()", contextNode);
  for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
   node = nodeList[i];
   switch (node.nodeType) {
    case node.TEXT_NODE:
     tag = "text()";
     break;
    case node.ELEMENT_NODE:
     tag = NS.prefixer(node.namespaceURI) + ":" + node.localName;
     break;
    default:
     tag = false;
     break;
   }
   if (tag) {
    precedingList = XPath.evaluate("preceding-sibling::" + tag, node);
    followingList = XPath.evaluate("following-sibling::" + tag, node);
    if (precedingList.length + followingList.length) {
     tag += "[" + (precedingList.length + 1) + "]";
    }
    ret.push(tag);
   }
  }
  return ret.join("/");
 },
};

var XSLT = {
 transformToFragment : function(dataNode, templateDoc, ownerDoc) {
  var xslt,
   uri, tmpDoc, nodeList, node, i,
   retFragment = false;
  try {
   //xsl:import parsen, fÃ¼r Chrome+Safari
   try {
    while (node = XPath.evaluate("//xsl:import", templateDoc)[0]) {
     uri = node.getAttribute("href");
     if (tmpDoc = DOM.loadDocument(uri)) {
      nodeList = XPath.evaluate("/xsl:stylesheet/*", tmpDoc);
      for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
       node.parentNode.appendChild(templateDoc.importNode(nodeList[i], true));
      }
     }
     node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
   } catch(e) {
    console.log("XSLT Error: could not process xsl:import elements");
    console.log(e);
   }
   if (window.XSLTProcessor) {
    xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
    xslt.importStylesheet(templateDoc);
    retFragment = xslt.transformToFragment(dataNode, ownerDoc);
    if (!retFragment) {
     throw "XSLTProcessor.transformToFragment returned null!";
    }
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");
    //var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
    //var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
    xslt.stylesheet = templateDoc;
    xslt = xslt.createProcessor();
    xslt.input = dataNode;
    xslt.transform();
    retFragment = ownerDoc.importNode(xslProc.output, true);
    if (!retFragment) {
     throw "Msxml2.XSLTemplate.transform returned null!";
    }
   }
  } catch(e) {
   console.log("An error occured while attempting to XSL transform. :|");
   console.log("Data node:%o", dataNode);
   console.log("Template document:%o", templateDoc);
   console.log("Owner document:%o", ownerDoc);
   console.log("Exception:%o", e);
   retFragment = ownerDoc.createDocumentFragment();
  }
  return retFragment;
 },
 transformToNode : function(dataNode, templateDoc, ownerDoc) {
  return this.transformToFragment(dataNode, templateDoc, ownerDoc).firstChild;
 },
};

var UnicodeMapper = {
 fontList : {},
 outputNodes : undefined,
 unicodeDocument : undefined,
 unicodeURI : document.currentScript.getAttribute('src').replace('unicode.js', 'unicode-conversion.xml'),
 init : function() {
  var fontNodeList, fontNode, labelNode, spanNode, i, nodeList, j, key, val, font, fontName;
  if (!this.initialized) {
   this.fontList = {};
   
   this.unicodeDocument = DOM.loadDocument(this.unicodeURI);
   if (this.unicodeDocument) {
    fontNodeList = this.unicodeDocument.getElementsByTagName("font");
    for (i = 0; i < fontNodeList.length; i++) {
     fontNode = fontNodeList[i];
     fontName = fontNode.getAttribute("name");
     font = {};
     nodeList = fontNode.getElementsByTagName("letter");
     for (j = 0; j < nodeList.length; j++) {
      key = nodeList[j].getAttribute("source");
      val = nodeList[j].getAttribute("target");
      font[key] = val;
     }
     this.fontList[fontName] = font;
    }
   }
   
   this.outputNodes = {};
   fontNode = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(NS.HTML, "fieldset")[0];
   for (fontName in this.fontList) {
    labelNode = document.createElementNS(NS.HTML, "label");
    spanNode = document.createElementNS(NS.HTML, "span");
    spanNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.convertWord(fontName, fontName)));
    labelNode.appendChild(spanNode);
    this.outputNodes[fontName] = document.createElementNS(NS.HTML, "textarea");
    this.outputNodes[fontName].setAttribute("class", "myParagraph");
    labelNode.appendChild(this.outputNodes[fontName]);
    fontNode.appendChild(labelNode);
   }
   
   this.initialized = true;
   
   this.typeCharacter(document.getElementsByTagNameNS(NS.HTML, "textarea")[0]);
  }
 },
 typeCharacter : function(inputNode) {
  var text, currentChar, i, fontType, outputNode, outputText, isUpperCase, codePoint, inputText;
  this.init();
  inputText = inputNode.value;
  outputText = {};
  
  //initialize output
  for (fontType in this.fontList) {
   outputText[fontType] = "";
  }
  
  //generate output
  for (fontType in this.fontList) {
   outputText[fontType] = this.convertWord(inputText, fontType);
  }
  
  //set output
  for (fontType in this.fontList) {
   if (outputNode = this.outputNodes[fontType]) {
    outputNode.value = outputText[fontType];
   }
  }
 },
 convertWord : function(inputText, fontType) {
  var outputText, currentChar;
  outputText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
   currentChar = inputText[i];
   if (this.fontList[fontType] && this.fontList[fontType][currentChar]) {
    currentChar = this.fontList[fontType][currentChar];
   }
   //Special stuff
   switch (fontType) {
    case "underlined-single":
     currentChar += "Ì²";
     break;
    case "Double Underline":
     currentChar += "Í‡";
     break;
    case "strikethrough-single":
     currentChar += "Ì¶";
     break;
    case "crosshatch":
     currentChar += "Ì·";
     break;
   }
   outputText += currentChar;
  }
  /*
  if (fontType === tableFlip) {
   outputText = this.flipString(outputText);
  }
  //*/
  return outputText;
 },
 flipString : function(str) {
  var ret, i;
  ret = "";
  for (i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   ret += str[i];
  }
  return ret;
 },
};

addEventListener(
 "load",
 function(eve) {
  UnicodeMapper.init();
 },
 false
);
```

Comment: What is the exception you're getting? If it's about CORS, the problem is that you're trying to load content from another domain.

Comment: No, I solved all CORS problems, but the problem is I don't know what exception this one is. It is just an XML exception.about the XMLHttpRequest. I looked into the XML to see if it is malformed but it isn't.

Comment: That's **A LOT** of  code :/